# How to call a method from property file using Java and Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently Working on **Selenium WebDriver** and code I'm writing in **Java**.

I have created a MasterScript called `Master.java` which is the main script and it looks like this:

```
package test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
public class MasterScript {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

//*****************************************************
//   Calling Methods
//*****************************************************

    LoginOneReports utilObj = new LoginOneReports ();
    WebDriver driver;
    driver=utilObj.setUp();
    if(utilObj.Login()){
        System.out.println("Login sucessfully completed");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Login failed");
        System.exit(0);
    }

NewPR utilObj1 = new NewPR(driver); // instead of calling one PR it need to pick from the property file and it need to select the KPI in UI

    if(utilObj1.test()){
    System.out.println("NewPR KPI page has opened");
    } else {
        System.out.println("NewPR KPI not able to open");
    }
    FilterSection utilObj2 =new FilterSection(driver);
    utilObj2.FilterMatching();
    }   
}
```

Put this dynamic values in the property file where each and every time it need to go to the property file and fetch the value, based on the value the related java file need to called.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi Just for example we will call the property file as setup.txt

say for example you have a url in ur setup file as "internal.url=https://google.com"

create a constructor

```
public MasterScript() throws IO Exception
 {
  setup_details();
   }
```

public void setup_details()throws IOException{

```
    FileInputStream inStream;
    inStream = new FileInputStream(new File("Setupfiles\\setup.txt"));
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(inStream);
    internal_url=prop.getProperty("internal.url");
        }
```

---

IN THE SETUP FILE*

internal.url=https://google.com

name the txt file as setup.txt

---

Now while using that in the main class u can just use "driver.get(internal_url);"

Hope This helps you...